# If $ Y $ is irreducible set so is $cl(Y)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $ Y $ is irreducible set so is $cl(Y)$.

If $cl(Y)$ is reducible then $cl(Y)= A \cup B$ where both $A$ and $B$ is closed in $cl(Y)$. Now how do we proceed?

Comment: What do closed sets in $\overline{Y}$ look like?  What do they look like in $Y$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $Y$ is an irreducible subset of a larger topological space $X$.  If $\overline{Y} = A \cup B$, with $A$ and $B$ closed sets of $\overline{Y}$, then $A$ and $B$ are actually closed sets in $X$.  Then $$Y = Y \cap \overline{Y} = Y \cap (A \cup B) = (Y \cap A) \cup (Y \cap B)$$ with $Y \cap A$ and $Y \cap B$ closed subsets of $Y$.  Since $Y$ is irreducible, one of these closed sets, say $Y \cap A$, is equal to $Y$.  Thus $Y \subseteq A$, and hence $\overline{Y} \subseteq A$.  But then $\overline{Y} = A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $cl(Y)$ is reducible so that $cl(Y)=A\cup B$. Then $Y\subset A\cup B$ so $Y\subset A$ or $Y\subset B$. Assume the former. But $A$ is closed so $cl(Y)\subset A$ and $A\subset cl(Y)$ so $A=cl(Y)$.

Comment: Why $Y \subset A \cup B$ will imply $Y \subset A$ or $Y \subset B$ ?

Comment: @user152715 Otherwise $Y=Y\cap A \cup Y\cap B$ which is obviously not true.